# Magento Notifications Sent To Everyone or Just Me?

Tags: magento-1.7, security, patches

I think the patches for the latest security issue with Magento has been installed, but I keep getting messages in the Admin area saying it is critical that I install the patches. Am I getting this messsage because the patch is not installed?

Comment: test your store with the following: https://shoplift.byte.nl/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No,

They are just that - messages. Everyone is getting them, including those that are patched.

Just shows how serious this one is, and how urgent it is to apply the patch.

I don't ever recall magento pushing out an alert to patch (but then I am growing old, so maybe I just forgot)

The site given by Thomas in the comments works great. If it says it is patched, it is patched.

Comment: No, they sent no notification on either. One is dated October 2014, the other February 2015. I am on the email notification list, never got an email or an in Magento notification... Until the one everyone is talking about, had every install of Magento popping the panic warning and had an email both at home and work... About 2 months late for the newest one and 6 months late on the older one... Hmm. This fine tool just going to waste. My notification on 5344 came through this website 6 days after it was released back in February because somebody asked a question.